# Python selenium find element returns nothing

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I would like to find titles contain '募集说明书', but the following codes just return nothing.

No error, just nothing. empty results.

```
driver.get('http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/bond/notice/index.html')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
datefield_st = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='input-group-wrap form-control dropdown-btn']/input[1]")))
datefield_st.click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='calendar-control'][1]//div[3]//a"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='monthselect'][1]//li[text()='{}']".format("1")))).click()
s1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-left')
s1.send_keys("2022-1-1")
s2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-right')
s2.send_keys("2022-1-18")
driver.find_element_by_id("query-btn").click()
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    try:       
        links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'募集说明书')]]")))]
        titles=[title.text for title in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pull-left ellipsis title-text' and contains(text(), '募集说明书')]//parent::a")))]
        dates=[date.text for date in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pull-left ellipsis title-text' and contains(text(), '募集说明书')]//ancestor::td//following-sibling::td")))]
        for link, title, date in zip(links, titles, dates):
            print(link,title,date)
```

```
<div class="text-title-box">
                            
<a attachformat="pdf" attachpath="/disc/disk03/finalpage/2022-01-21/bb9854c5-9d89-4914-a6ea-219b487b874a.PDF" target="_blank" href="/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?bd5fd845-e810-42d3-98b3-d2501daaabc3" class="annon-title-link">
 <span class="pull-left title-text multiline" title="22新资01：新疆金投资产管理股份有限公司2022年面向专业投资者公开发行公司债券（第一期）募集说明书">22新资01：新疆金投资产管理股份有限公司2022年面向专业投资者公开发行公司债券（第一期）募集说明书</span>
 <span class="pull-left ellipsis title-icon" title="点击下载公告文件"><img src="http://res.static.szse.cn/modules/disclosure/images/icon_pdf.png">(5822k)</span>
 <span class="titledownload-icon" title="点击下载公告文件"></span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Could someone please help with this issue? Many thanks

Comment: Is there an error message or ? If so, please edit your question and add the full error message properly formatted. Also, add the relevant HTML to the question properly formatted.

Comment: Hi, I said it returns nothing, meaning no error, but nothing returns. The HTML is properly formatted, it just the website I use. And I just don't know why it should be closed

Comment: Try to make a code more simple for debug. I think you are overcomplicating it

Comment: You mess up time.sleep() with Selenium's waits. What is the reason for using `while` condition?

Comment: Hi thanks! Actually I do a loop for clicking' next page', so I use while condition

Comment: @Joyce There's no HTML in this question. Please add the relevant HTML, properly formatted. Have you tried your locators in the browser dev tools to make sure they are correct? Have you looked to see if the elements are in an IFRAME?

Comment: This looks like the elements are simply not found. Since you use "visibility_of_all_elements_located" it makes sense that there are no errors - you are getting an empty list in response. I tried pasting your xpath in devtools and got nothing too.

Comment: @JeffC Hi thanks, please find my update questions, sorry I do not know how to view in IFRAME..

Comment: pull-left title-text multiline, pull-left ellipsis title-icon is the class names not pull-left ellipsis title-text.

Comment: @YuMa thanks! I find I write the wrong class name..lol

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Hey thanks! Here is the problem！ I see, seems the website changed the format, thank you!!

Comment: @Joyce IFRAME is an HTML tag. Right-click on one of the desired elements on the page and choose Inspect. That will highlight the element in the DOM. Now move upwards in the DOM and see if an IFRAME is a parent element.

Comment: @JeffC Hi thanks for your help. I will give a try on this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Elements matching `//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'募集说明书')]]` XPath are located on the bottom of presented search results, they are out of the visible screen until you scroll them into the view.
Also, you are using a wrong locators for `titles`. See my fixes there.
The same about `dates`.
Also there is no need to use `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located` 3 times there. Since elements are found (and scrolled into the view) you can simply get them by `driver.find_elements`.
I also see no need for `while True:` loop here, it will break your code from complete after getting those 2 elements data, but I leaved it as is since you mentioned you intend to click "next page" there.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver.get('http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/bond/notice/index.html')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
datefield_st = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='input-group-wrap form-control dropdown-btn']/input[1]")))
datefield_st.click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='calendar-control'][1]//div[3]//a"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='monthselect'][1]//li[text()='{}']".format("1")))).click()
s1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-left')
s1.send_keys("2022-1-1")
s2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-right')
s2.send_keys("2022-1-18")
driver.find_element_by_id("query-btn").click()
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    try:       
        lower_link =wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"(//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'募集说明书')]])[last()]")))
        actions.move_to_element(lower_link).perform()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'募集说明书')]]")]
        titles=[title.text for title in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class,'pull-left') and contains(text(), '募集说明书')]//parent::a")]
        dates=[date.text for date in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class,'pull-left') and contains(text(), '募集说明书')]//ancestor::td//following-sibling::td")]
        for link, title, date in zip(links, titles, dates):
            print(link,title,date)
```